# How to sum running total field for each group in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

i have problem in crystall report,

Here is my code following many reference site in google,

```
// {@reset}
//place in group header
whileprintingrecords;
global numbervar Sum_Cumm_Sum:=0;

// {@increment}
//place in section detail
whileprintingrecords;
global numbervar Sum_Cumm_Sum:=Sum_Cumm_Sum+{@getIP};

// {@display}
//place in group footer
whileprintingrecords;
global numbervar Sum_Cumm_Sum;
```

Where getIP is Formula,

```
{#sumKN}/{#sumSKS}
```

and code in it is running total field with **reset on change group**,

```
{#sumKN} is running total field for field KN 
{#sumSKS} = is running total field for field SKS
```

============================================================

I use all this code, but in `Sum_Cumm_Sum:=Sum_Cumm_Sum+{@getIP}`, I can't get the right value.

Here is my report view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSmsB.png

Comment: might be a duplicate from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350764/crystal-reports-running-total-for-specific-groups

Comment: thx for your reply, i have  check it  but it not sum running total field for each group but it only  sum record with specific purpose, please see my image for detail explanation, thx

Comment: Place this '@increment' formula into group footer instead of detail section (before '@display' formula) - currently it is summed for every detail section, which according to your image seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I see as you placed in detail section  your formula is working correctly, Now you want to see the summation of values in footer then you need to write saperate formula to sum `index....` in footer section so that it sumarizes it saperatley.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what should i write in the formula? if i write `sum ({@getIP})` this show error `this field cannot be summarize`

Comment: Ok it means that it is alreaqdy a summarized filed so write again a running total to summarize the option at footer. What is the filed that is present in `index...` in footer

Comment: i'm sorry but i dont understand, what is mean `index`?  in group footer, i have 2 formula, first @getIP it have `{#sumKN}/{#sumSKS}`, and second @Sum_Cumm_Sum_Display it have `whileprintingrecords;global numbervar Sum_Cumm_Sum;` in it.

Comment: in your attachment 2 nd row in semister 2. I guess that one should get summarized to get the value `IPK` right. then try to write running total for that one

Comment: oh, the IPK is use `whileprintingrecords; global numbervar Sum_Cumm_Sum;` it based on divide of sumarize field `K.N` and `SKS`, I short it with create formula called @getIP where `{#sumKN}/{#sumSKS}`, you can see the value of @getIP under `Mata Kuliah` in the image. But what I want is summarize of IPK (example: show in image).

Answer (score 0):

Either use a manual running total OR a `running-total field`, not both.  By the way, a `running-total field` only works in a `footer` section.

A better approach:

```
{#sumKN} - field is {table.KN}; summarize for all records; reset after change in group

{#sumSKS} - field is {table.SKS}; summarize for all records; reset after change in group

// place in `footer` section
//{@ratio}

// optional
// EvaluateAfter({#sumKN});
// EvaluateAfter({#sumSKS});

{#sumKN} / {#sumSKS}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply, you right and thx for correction too, so Is it imposiblle to do what i want?